# How to do random shuffling in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, shuffle

I would like to write a script in Python and I have a word for ABDEB in my hand. I want to make this word into an array and then shuffle the letters inside the word and get the words in different combinations. In addition, these combinations may contain repetitive letters and make a column like;

BBBED,
EEEEA,
ADDEA,

etc.

After all, I would like to get these words into a text file.

How can I do that?

I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is your friend, according to the docs

> random.shuffle(x[, random]) .
>   Shuffle the sequence x in place.

```
import random

#Convert string to list of chars
li = list('ABDEB')

for i in range(5):
    #Shuffle the list, the last shuffled list is shuffled every time
    random.shuffle(li)
    #Convert list to string again and print
    print(''.join(li))
```

Output might look like

```
DBEBA
ABEBD
BABDE
BADEB
BDAEB
```

Or you can start with the same base string every time

```
import random

for i in range(5):
    li = list('ABDEB')
    random.shuffle(li)
    print(''.join(li))
```

For shuffle with replacement, you can actually use [itertools.combibations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and it will give you `all` possible combinations in one go, then use [random.choce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick an element from there

From the docs:

> itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)
>   Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable allowing individual elements to be repeated more than once.
>
> random.choice(seq)
>   Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import random

li = list('ABDEB')

#Get all possible combinations with repetitions
res = [''.join(item) for item in combinations_with_replacement(li,len(li))]

#Use random.choice to pick a element from res
for i in range(5):
    print(random.choice(res))
```

Output will look like

```
DDEEE
ABBBE
ADDDD
BBDDB
AADDB
```

Comment: Thanks, so how do i make more than 5 words?

Comment: You can make as many combinations as you want, I just ran the function 5 times to show an example!

Comment: Yeah, I just change the range limit. Thank you so much!

Comment: Last question is, I just also want to repetitive letters in this string. What should I add to code?

Comment: Updated the answer to handle that scenario, please check @MustafaBerkŞenal  and let me know if any additional questions!

Comment: Hi @MustafaBerkŞenal Please kindly accept the answer if it helped you by clicking the tick next to the answer! :)

Comment: Hi, now what I want to do is:

I would like to keep the letters in this word and then get a new dictionary of letters and assign different letters for each index from this dictionary. How can I do that?

Comment: When you mean a dictionary of letters , what will the key and values?

Comment: When you mean a dictionary of letters , what will the key and values? @MustafaBerkŞenal ?

Comment: The values will be (X,T,Y,Z,M,N). I want to change the characters from that dictionary one by one. @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: So A->X B-Y C-Z like that @MustafaBerkŞenal

Comment: Yes, it should be like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import itertools
x = list('ABDEB')
a=[''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=len(x))]
print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['AAAAA', 'AAAAB', 'AAAAD', 'AAAAE', 'AAAAB', 'AAABA',...]
```

To save to file use the below command.

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('test.txt', a, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: Hi, now what I want to do is:

I would like to keep the letters in this word and then get a new dictionary of letters and assign different letters for each index from this dictionary. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways would be to use the random.shuffle function: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

As for writing the words to a file, this is a fairly trivial exercise so I would suggest a little bit of searching for that answer as there are many ways to do it and your specification is a little unclear.

Comment: I would like to keep the letters in this word and then get a new dictionary of letters and assign different letters for each index from this dictionary. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use random.shuffle. It's faster than a naive algorithm, as it uses the Fisher-Yates shuffle. It runs in O(n) time and it is a perfect shuffle.

Your own implementation would likely run in O(n^2) time